# Postgresql Average Time it takes to go 5000 miles to calc next oil change

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have two tables.

**Table 1:** service_sales_closed

**Table 2:** service_sales_details

**service_sales_closed:**

```
ronumber - Repair Order Number
custno - Customer Number
closedate - Closed RO Date
mileage - Mileage
vehid - VIN
```

**service_sales_details:**

```
ronumber
opcode - Operation Code (What type of repair)
```

**What I would like to do is:**

Per vehicle on a specific ronumber (lets say its oilchange) **how much time does it take that vehicle to go about 5000 miles**. Then if possible on todays date (or yesterdays) be able to **determine if that vehicle should go in for an oilchange in the next week** or so based on how long it takes that vehicle to drive 5000 miles. I do need to make sure they **haven't come in recently for an oilchange**, although that maybe negated because of the intelligence of the selection.

I have the following to determine an oil change based on 23-30days since a vehicle has been in for an oilchange:

```
   SELECT <*noted fields*>
     FROM service_sales_closed
LEFT JOIN service_sales_details ON service_sales_closed.ronumber = service_sales_details.ronumber
LEFT JOIN vehicle ON servicesalesclosed.vehid = vehicle.vehid
    WHERE service_sales_closed.closedate >= current_date - integer '90' 
      AND service_sales_closed.closedate <= current_date - integer '83' 
      AND service_sales_details.opcode = '04DOZ1' 
      AND service_sales_closed.vehid NOT IN (SELECT service_sales_closed.vehid
                                               FROM service_sales_closed
                                          LEFT JOIN service_sales_details ON service_sales_closed.ronumber = service_sales_details.ronumber
                                              WHERE service_sales_closed.closedate > current_date - integer '83' 
                                                AND service_sales_details.opcode = 'oilchange')
```

Comment: Use table aliases to make your queries less verbose.

Answer (score 1):

> how much time does it take that vehicle to go about 5000 miles

Well I guess that's the main problem.

Where does the "5000 miles" come from ? Is it your recommended interval between oil changes ? Perhaps you'd like to schedule other maintenance operations which occur at different intervals (tires, whatever). So you'd need a way to encode those intervals.

I'll make a little example :

```
CREATE TABLE service_types (
  st_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  st_name TEXT, 
  st_interval_miles INTEGER, 
  st_interval_time INTERVAL
);

CREATE TABLE vehicles ( veh_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, birth_date DATE );

CREATE TABLE service_sales ( 
 ss_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
 ss_mileage INTEGER NOT NULL,
 ss_date DATE NOT NULL,
 veh_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES vehicles( veh_id )
);

CREATE TABLE service_details( 
 ss_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES service_sales( ss_id ),
 st_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES service_types( st_id )
);
```

Let's fill this :

```
INSERT INTO service_types (st_name,st_interval_miles,st_interval_time) VALUES
('oil change', 5000, '2 YEAR'),
('timing belt', 60000, '5 YEAR');

INSERT INTO vehicles (veh_id,birth_date) VALUES (1,'2009-09-01'),(2,'2009-08-01');

INSERT INTO service_sales (ss_id, veh_id, ss_mileage, ss_date) VALUES
(1, 1, 5000,  '2010-01-01'),
(2, 1, 12000, '2010-04-01'),
(3, 1, 18000, '2010-09-01'),
(4, 2, 5000,  '2010-01-01'),
(5, 2, 10000, '2010-08-01'),
(6, 2, 16000, '2010-12-01');

INSERT INTO service_details (ss_id,st_id) VALUES
(1,1),
(2,1),
(3,1),
(4,1),
(5,1),
(6,1);

SELECT * FROM vehicles v
JOIN service_sales USING (veh_id)
JOIN service_details USING (ss_id)
JOIN service_types USING (st_id);

 st_id | ss_id | veh_id | birth_date | ss_mileage |  ss_date   |  st_name   | st_interval_miles | st_interval_time 
-------+-------+--------+------------+------------+------------+------------+-------------------+------------------
     1 |     1 |      1 | 2009-09-01 |       5000 | 2010-01-01 | oil change |              5000 | 2 years
     1 |     2 |      1 | 2009-09-01 |      12000 | 2010-04-01 | oil change |              5000 | 2 years
     1 |     3 |      1 | 2009-09-01 |      18000 | 2010-09-01 | oil change |              5000 | 2 years
     1 |     4 |      2 | 2009-08-01 |       5000 | 2010-01-01 | oil change |              5000 | 2 years
     1 |     5 |      2 | 2009-08-01 |      10000 | 2010-08-01 | oil change |              5000 | 2 years
     1 |     6 |      2 | 2009-08-01 |      16000 | 2010-12-01 | oil change |              5000 | 2 years
```

Now for your estimation : You need to compute the "average speed" of the vehicle, that is the distance it did, divided by time, but you need to choose the interval. You could use the interval between the last 2 services, or an average over all the times your shop saw this vehicle. That's up to you.

Once you have this, you can compute how much time it will take that vehicle to do the 5000 miles since the last recorded oil change.

Let's say you gonna estimate the average speed over all the times your shop saw this vehicle.

This means for each vehicle you take the last and first service records and compute the mileage and time differences :

```
SELECT foo.veh_id, 
(last.ss_mileage-first.ss_mileage) AS miles, 
(last.ss_date-first.ss_date) AS days FROM (
 SELECT veh_id, min( ss_id ) AS first_ss_id, max( ss_id ) AS last_ss_id 
 FROM service_sales GROUP BY veh_id
) foo 
JOIN service_sales first ON (first.ss_id=first_ss_id) 
JOIN service_sales last ON (last.ss_id=last_ss_id)
WHERE first_ss_id != last_ss_id AND last.ss_date <= first.ss_date + '1 WEEK'::INTERVAL;
 veh_id | miles | days 
--------+-------+------
      1 | 13000 |  243
      2 | 11000 |  334
```

So we know how many miles each vehicle did in how many days. The WHERE condition eliminates vehicles which have only one service record or that your shop only knows from less than 1 week which would not give a very good estimation. You could use a LEFT JOIN and some COALESCE work to substitute this with a fudged default value.

Now from the last oil change and average speed we can get a value for the next oil change :

```
WITH 
avgspeeds AS (SELECT foo.veh_id, 
    (last.ss_mileage-first.ss_mileage) AS miles, 
    (last.ss_date-first.ss_date) AS days FROM (
     SELECT veh_id, min( ss_id ) AS first_ss_id, max( ss_id ) AS last_ss_id 
     FROM service_sales GROUP BY veh_id
        ) foo 
    JOIN service_sales first ON (first.ss_id=first_ss_id) 
    JOIN service_sales last ON (last.ss_id=last_ss_id)
    WHERE first_ss_id != last_ss_id AND last.ss_date >= first.ss_date + '1 WEEK'::INTERVAL
),

last_services AS (SELECT 
 veh_id, 
     st_id, 
 max(ss_date) AS last_service_date
FROM service_sales
JOIN service_details USING (ss_id)
GROUP BY veh_id, st_id)

SELECT *,
  COALESCE( last_service_date, birth_date ) + least(
     (st.st_interval_miles * a.days / a.miles) * '1 DAY'::INTERVAL,
     st.st_interval_time) AS next_service_date
FROM
service_types st
CROSS JOIN vehicles v
JOIN avgspeeds a USING (veh_id)
LEFT JOIN last_services ls USING (veh_id,st_id);
```

Monster query eh ? Seems to give the right results.

Good luck ;)

> Why do you put unnecessary prefixes before each column name? 
>   I really hate it when people do this, it makes every query so damn ugly,

Because :
- It makes queries readable
- I hate to have several "id" fields in the result sets coming from whatever tables
- Foreign keys should have the same names in both tables, allowing the use of NATURAL JOIN and the very useful JOIN .. USING
- I don't care that you don't like it

> and it's even worse if you use an orm. 
>   Column aliasing is already in the sql standard, use it

If your ORM doesn't allow you to define table column names that are different from object member names, and write large (yet readabe) SQL queries, you need a real ORM.

Comment: Why do you put unnecessary prefixes before each column name? I really hate it when people do this, it makes every query so damn ugly, and it's even worse if you use an orm. Column aliasing is already in the sql standard, use it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!!!  Of course I have issues!!!
This is a server I cannot change or add tables to and the version is PostgreSQL 8.3.6...

That being said I'm getting this when I run the code from first part of your answer _italic_ schema "last" does not exist at... _italic_

I am also calling this all from Perl using perls DBI:Pg

Comment: @peufeu could you please let me know if that version can run these statements?!  If not maybe I could pull and dump a dataset from their server to mine and then run it?!

Comment: @ryeguy: Prefixing with a table alias is a **GOOD** habit.  You'll get ambiguous column errors in the event of duplicates otherwise. Additionally - as readers, we know which table the column came from.  "ugly" doesn't have context in programming - it's all about habits that make code easier to maintain.

Comment: I picked up this prefixing habit a few years ago. Maintaining code from "before", where column names have no prefixes, gives me headaches.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: No, it's not. You're forcing me to use prefixes even when I'm only selecting from one table. I don't need prefixes then, there is no chance of ambiguity. You simply add a requirement to your company's coding standards that any and all joins must use the database's table aliasing feature, and you enforce this in your code reviews.

Comment: @ryeguy: Yes, still use an alias for a single table -- for consistency.  You've yet to provide a legitimate reason not to use table aliases, beyond "it's too much *work*".

Comment: @OMG Ponies: My argument is that it's not necessary. And the semantics bother me. A table called `service_details` represents service details, obviously. A service detail does not have a property called `ss_name`, it has a property called `name`. The database **already has** an alias system, there is no need to reinvent it. It works just fine.

Comment: @ryeguy: Every database has an error for ambiguous column references (when more than one table has identical column names, but there's nothing to distinguish which to use).  That makes it necessary, nothing about semantics.  You can't definitively say a query will be updated where such a situation will never happen.  Your example of a column name is too generic to fly in any DBA review I've been in - `name` of what?!  What do you do when you need two name columns...  "the database already has an alias system" - WTF?!  Synonyms are not aliases.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: "Name of what!?". Of the logical object you're storing in each row. Service details are stored in the `service_details` table. How is this hard to understand? `name` is a property of a `ServiceDetail`. A table is a collection of relevant data. And what in the world does your system accomplish that aliases don't? `SELECT u.id as user_id, p.id as profile_id FROM users u JOIN profiles p ON p.id = u.id`. Done, without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @ryeguy: But your example fails when you need to add a second name related column.  Which I explained previously... You grasp *desperately* at straws...

Comment: @OMG Ponies: If you had a `ServiceDetails` business object, you wouldn't give it a property named `ss_name`, you'd give it a property called `name`. If you can't apply the same logic to tables as you can objects, then you aren't making a valid argument. And before you say "tables don't always map directly to business objects", I know they don't. But a table is still an object in *some* sense. It's still a set of data that is related with one another, or else it would be in separate tables.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: What do you mean a second name related column? I showed an example where 2 columns are the same name. Show me an example where your version of aliases do something that standard sql aliases can't.

Comment: @ryeguy: `name` fails Spolsky's Hallway Test.  I'd like to say your delusion was entertaining...

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Sorry, that's an empty argument. I agree that `name` is useless without context, but you won't ever be without context. You'll have a hashmap that's named something like `serviceDetail`, or you'd have an instance of the `ServiceDetail` class. The irony here is `ss_name` isn't even a good name. What is ss? You wouldn't know unless you had context. And if you have context, you just proved my point. Let me guess - you're a .NET or Java developer? I can't get over how verbose both communities try to make everything. And you wonder why people "flee" to Ruby and Python.

Comment: @ryeguy: "ss_name" was your suggested alternative -- keep trying ;)  It's not "verbose", it's a practice that transcends language to make code maintainable.  I'm sorry you lack the business & life experience to realize that.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: `ss_name` was the example used in this answer we're commenting in. I'm going to guess that you use the entire table name as a prefix, which is *much* worse and still doesn't change any of the points I've made against it. I see you've resorted to personal attacks, are dodging simple questions and retorts, so I'll just assume that I've won here. Elegance and beauty in code are important, and using something that smells like hungarian notation is essentially a code smell.

Comment: @ryeguy: You'll have to assume, because you've done nothing but demonstrate your prejudice.  I think if you take a day, and come back to read this -- you'll be as embarrassed as you should've originally been.